# Split a polygon layer with another polygon layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, splitting

I have two layers :
[image]

- The red layer with 2 features : 1 and 3.
- The green layer with 3 features : area 1, area 2 and area 3.

I need a layer which contain my green layer split by my red layer. In that example, I would have a polygon layer with 6 features in it.
I would like the attribute table like :

```
area 1 | NULL
area 1 | 1
area 2 | NULL
area 2 | 3
area 3 | 1
area 3 | NULL
```

I didn't see such an algorithm in QGIS. What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: This operation is not a `clip`. I tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might need to use the **Union** tool to get your six features with the same attribute format you are looking for. You can access this from the `Vector` menu or from the `Processing Toolbox`.

Comment: Yes ! The name `Union` is not obvious for me, I didn't see this operation as a union. But yes, that's it. However, I got 8 features in the union layer : 2 features without area 1 or 2. But I can easily remove them with a QGIS expression because the area is NULL.

Comment: @Gustry - Ahh good point but glad you got it working :)